# Is there a way to auto format SQL in R?

Tags: sql, r

I wrote a script that auto generates a lot SQL code. It works but it's all just one giant line. Is there an easy way to auto format it?

I found ways to auto format SQL in Python and other tools, but not in R.

Example SQL:

```
create table bookings (ds DATE, id_reservation varchar(255), id_listing varchar(255)); insert into bookings (ds, id_reservation, id_listing) VALUES('2010-11-02','242805deab','28e5c6fa-4038-4994-b8cd-554578033e7b'),('2010-09-20','f82ed9bf0c','e0ef7dcf-74d9-4a94-8047-9287efea1d50');
```

Comment: It might help somewhat to narrow things a little bit: where do you want the SQL to eventually end up? Do you mean you want to display the SQL on the R console as a formatted query? Or do you want to write it to a file such that the resulting SQL file is formatted?

Comment: Could you paste here some sample code, or result?  If you can add after each "line" (you would like to have) an  "\n", then you can print that one long line into more lines. Or you can use writeLines() for better output.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [sqlparseR](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqlparseR/versions/0.1.0/topics/sql_format) is what you need:

```
> sqlparseR::sql_format(example_SQL, reindent = TRUE) %>% cat()
create table bookings (ds DATE, id_reservation varchar(255), id_listing varchar(255));

insert into bookings (ds, id_reservation, id_listing)
VALUES('2010-11-02','242805deab','28e5c6fa-4038-4994-b8cd-554578033e7b'),
      ('2010-09-20','f82ed9bf0c','e0ef7dcf-74d9-4a94-8047-9287efea1d50');
```